# Защита сайта от физического копирования

Tags: защита, php

Представим, есть сайтик самопальный, несколько папок + несколько php файлов + бд mysql. Охота сайт защитить от физического копирования. Понятное дело абсолютной защиты не будет. Но охота делать хоть какие то шаги в этом направлении. Смысл прост - человек, у которого доступ к хостингу, копирует файлы сайта + бд, ставит его локально или в другое место. Сайт в свою очередь запускаться не должен. В идеале что бы еще было проблемой код прочитать. Кто что может посоветовать? Защитить хочу PHP, и по возможности MySQL. Так что даже ребята с хостинга имели геморрой если захотят копировать

Изначально думал в пользу такой конструкции:

- сайт при включении отправляет POST запрос к другому сайту (получает ключ)
- далее ключ обрабатывается, получаем ключ 2 + пакет правил (математических)
- с помощью полученного вычисляем содержимое сайта

Это ужасно и отвратительно, но разбор достаточно больших математических алгоритмов - согласитесь будет большим камнем преткновения, чем разбор кода типа:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='mysite.ru'){
      include('site/mysiteall.php');
}
```

Есть еще метод кажется 'обфускации' - его прошу не предлагайте. (раскладываем код на определенные знаки, что нечитабельно, потом функцией собираем его и выполняем)

p.s. сори, что в праздник

Comment: купите рэк в DC и поставьте к нему автоматчика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ioncube](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140159/)

Смотрите раздел "Создание лицензии".

Если оставить код без обфускации - его можно будет запросто проанализировать, например, пройтись дебаггером, и сделать нужные исправления, чтобы работало вне вашего хостинга.

Answer (score 0):

> > В идеале что бы еще было проблемой код прочитать.

[ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/)

Естественно не бесплатное решение.

Вот вроде бесплатное [решение](http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler). Но я не уверен что его можно использовать на хостинге. Как минимум нужен vps.